# How to choose a value from cell in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, merge, command, cells

How can I choose correctly value from cell in Excel? I know that my problem is with command for select cell.

**My actually scripts:**

```
List<string> wsList = new List<string>();
DataTable schemaTable;
DataSet da = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string name;
string FileName = fullpath;
string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
string _Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
// Checking for the extentions, if XLS connect using Jet OleDB
if (_Extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    _ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", FileName);
}
// Use ACE OleDb
else if (_Extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    _ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", FileName);
}

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_ConnectionString);

try
{
    con.Open();
    // Get schematable name from excel file
    schemaTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        wsList.Add(row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"));
    name = wsList[0];
    // Select values from cell in excel
    string strCmd = "SELECT J38 FROM [" + name + "]"; // I think that here is my main problem
    // Command for select value
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strCmd, con);

    da.Clear();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(da);
    UniqueValue.money.Add(double.Parse(da.ToString()));
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

**Image where you can watch what I need select: (Merged-Cell)**

[image]

**Debug:**

For one or more required parameters were not found, no value

Comment: any idea for help with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Merged cells and data adapters don't mix.  If this is a one-off, copy the values from the original worksheet into an empty workbook and unmerge the cells, do any other cleanup manually.  If this is a production process that needs to be repeated, and is high-volume, consider writing a VBA macro in the workbook to do the copypasta/cleanup process for you.